# why count(*) as name showing Undefined index: name

Tags: php, mysql, database

when fetching data from database php say undefined index for that row which is count(*) as name that name it not defined

```
SELECT location.location_name,
       employers.emp_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(present.present_date) AS present_days
        from present
        WHERE present_status='م' AND present.emp_id=employers.emp_id AND present.present_date between '$date1' AND '$date2') ,
       (SELECT COUNT(present.present_status) AS absent_days 
        from present
        WHERE present_status='غ' AND present.emp_id=employers.emp_id AND present.present_date between '$date1' AND '$date2'), 
       (SELECT COUNT(present.present_status) AS permission_absent_days
        from present
        WHERE present_status='غب' AND present.emp_id=employers.emp_id AND present.present_date between '$date1' AND '$date2'),
       (SELECT band.band_name AS training
        from band
        WHERE band_name='NoTraining' AND band.emp_id=employers.emp_id AND band.band_date between '$date1' AND '$date2'),
       (SELECT COUNT(band.band_name)AS employers_band
        from band
        WHERE band.emp_id=employers.emp_id AND band.band_date between '$date1' AND '$date2') 
FROM `present`, `employers`,`location`,`band`
WHERE  present.emp_id = employers.emp_id AND location.location_id = employers.location_id 
GROUP BY employers.emp_name 
ORDER BY employers.emp_name ASC
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I can't see `COUNT(*)` or an alias `name` in your SQL. Are you sure this is the correct SQL?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note how I have formatted your query. You will be far more likely to get answers to your question if you make it readable, as I have. Please read [ask] to learn how to ask a good question. When asking questions about SQL, please also take note of [mcve].

Comment: Show us the PHP code which throws that error

Answer (score 1):

The alias assignment should be *after* the closing paren of the subquery in the SELECT list

```
SELECT ...
     , ( SELECT ... AS foo FROM ... WHERE ... ) AS col_name
--                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  FROM
```

The alias `foo` assigned inside the subquery doesn't matter to the outer query. What matters to the outer query is the alias assigned to the expression in the SELECT list of the outer query, `col_name`.

(We can run the query in mysql command line client, and see the assigned to the column in the resultset. Or in the PHP code, we could inspect/vardump the array returned from the fetch.)

---

Some other issues appear to be semi-Cartesian product, multiple rows returned from multiple child tables cross joined together. Seems to be some join conditions missing.

I recommend ditching the old-school comma syntax for the join operation and using the `JOIN` keyword instead.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The suggestion above (assigning an alias to the subquery expression in the SELECT list of the outer query, may "work" , but I think there's significantly more wrong with the query.

With the correlated subqueries in the SELECT list, I don't think it's necessary to perform joins to `band` and `present` in the outer query. That's going to produce wonky results, when multiple rows are returned and cross joined. And if no matching row is returned from `band` or `present`, a row is going to missing from the resultset.

It looks to me (and I'm just guessing because we don't have a specification for what the query is supposed to return) ...

It looks to me like the intent is to return a result equivalent to the one returned by a query of this pattern:

```
SELECT l.location_name
     , e.emp_name

     , ( SELECT COUNT(pd.present_date) AS present_days
           FROM present pd
          WHERE pd.emp_id         = e.emp_id
            AND pd.present_status = '?'
            AND pd.present_date   BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
       ) AS present_days

     , ( SELECT COUNT(ad.present_status)
           FROM `present` ad
          WHERE ad.emp_id         = e.emp_id
            AND ad.present_status = '?'
            AND ad.present_date   BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
       ) AS absent_days

    , ( SELECT COUNT(pa.present_status)
          FROM `present` pa
         WHERE pa.emp_id          = e.emp_id
           AND pa.present_status  = '??'
           AND pa.present_date    BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
       ) AS permission_absent_days

    , ( SELECT MAX(tr.band_name)
          FROM `band` tr
         WHERE tr.emp_id          = e.emp_id
           AND tr.band_name       = 'NoTraining'
           AND tr.band_date       BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
      ) AS training

    , ( SELECT COUNT(eb.band_name)
          FROM `band` eb
         WHERE eb.emp_id          = e.emp_id
           AND eb.band_date       BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
      ) AS employers_band

  FROM `employers` e
  JOIN `location` l
    ON l.location_id = e.location_id
 ORDER
    BY e.emp_name ASC
```